# Compare a waiver CSV file to a file containing errors

Tags: perl

I need to build a waiver system for work purposes using the sample `waiver.csv` below. Stage error already printed in a error file (refer below `input.txt`). I need to check each line of error on `input.txt` against `waiver.csv` (with matched stage, process and block) and comes with below sample output. I need help on matching errors from the error file to errors from the `waiver.csv` file.

`waiver.csv`:

```
#process,#Block,#Stage name,#Waiver owner,#Justification,#Error msg
process1,block1,stage1,Alex,testing,Error: Port 0 does not exist
process1,block1,stage1,Alex,testing,Error: Port 1 does not exist
process1,block1,stage1,Alex,testing,Error: Port a0 does not exist
```

Error file (`input.txt`):

```
Stage: stage1
Process: process1
Block: block1

Error: Port 0 does not exist
Error: Port 1 does not exist
Error: Port a0 does not exist
Error: Port a1 does not exist
Error: Port b3 does not exist
Error: Nothing matched for port_list (SEL-005)
Error: Nothing matched for port_list (SEL-005)
Error: Port c5 does not exist
Error: Nothing matched for port_list (SEL-005)
Error: Nothing matched for port_list (SEL-005)
```

Expected output file:

```
WAIVED (3 waiver, 0 errors) - stage1,process1,block1:
    Error: Port 0 does not exist
    Error: Port 1 does not exist
    Error: Port a0 does not exist
    Waiver Owner: Alex
    Justification: testing

FAILED (No waiver, 4 errors) - stage1,process1,block1:
    Error: Nothing matched for port_list (SEL-005)
    Error: Port a1 does not exist
    Error: Port b3 does not exist
    Error: Port c5 does not exist
```

Short snippet of the code I am working on:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

# Define the file paths
my $input_file = 'input.txt';
my $waiver_file = 'waiver.csv';

# Read the waiver.csv file
my @waiver_msgs;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 }) or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();
open(my $waiver_fh, '<', $waiver_file) or die "Cannot open $waiver_file: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline($waiver_fh)) {
    push @waiver_msgs, $row->[5];  # Assuming error messages are in the 6th column (index 5)
}
close($waiver_fh);

# Read the input.txt file
open(my $input_fh, '<', $input_file) or die "Cannot open $input_file: $!";
while (my $line = <$input_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^Error: (.+)$/) {
        my $error_msg = $1;
        print "$error_msg\n";
        if (grep { $_ eq $error_msg } @waiver_msgs) {
            print "Error message '$error_msg' is waived.\n";
        } else {
            print "Error message '$error_msg' is not waived.\n";
        }
    }
}
close($input_fh);
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Show what you did so far and show where exactly you have problems, so that one can help you with the specific problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich edited the question. Literally I need idea how to achieve the output, will appreciate if someone could offer the help

Comment: You describe your goal. You show your code. What is your question? "Can you help?" is not a question on StackOverflow. Please try for [ask]. What of the shown code is not working? What are the symptoms? What is the difference between the achieved result and the desired result?

Comment: What is a waiver system? This did not really help me understand: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/de/worterbuch/englisch/waiver

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are parsing your 2 input files differently.  When you read in the waiver file, you retain the `Error:` prefix.  However, when you read in the error file, you **do not** retain the `Error:` prefix.  This is the reason your comparison fails.

Judging by your desired output, you want to retain `Error:`.  Since that is the case, you should change the capturing parentheses to include it.
Change:

```
if ($line =~ /^Error: (.+)$/) {
```

to:

```
if ($line =~ /^(Error: .+)$/) {
```

Or, since you are capturing the whole line, there is no need for capturing parentheses.  You can simplify the regular expression to just search for the error string at the start of the line, then set the error message to the whole line:

```
if ($line =~ /^Error: /) {
    my $error_msg = $line;
```